# How can I use SignalR in an Azure?

Tags: .net, azure

I'm having one azure account and I want to use signalR performance counter in azure web.
If any one has used if before please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very well documented in the following link.

[using-signalr-performance-counters-in-an-azure-web-role](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/using-signalr-performance-counters-in-an-azure-web-role)

Hope this will solve your problem.